# SSR is not working in Nuxtjs for my project, shifted from Vuejs to Nuxtjs

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I have just shifted from Vuejs to Nuxtjs. installed Nuxtjs. I have copied vuejs code to my Nuxtjs project. everything is working fine, except SSR. the reason to convert from vuejs to nuxtjs is because of ssr(server side rendering). I used to use created() lifecycle in vuejs to get information which is needed when i page is loaded. do i need to add extra thing on my pages so that my code get rendered in SSR? anything like any lifecycle, asyncData(), or anything that is needed for SSR? Thank you.

Comment: How do you guess the SSR is not working?